# String decoding in JavaScript under MeteorJS

Tags: meteor, decode

Mathias Bynens wrote a wonderful JavaScript library to decode strings that is not available in MeteorJS yet. 
How can I solve the problem?

My sample string is:

"I don’t do decoding"

and it doesn't seem to be any JavaScript function I can use to decode it. I didn't find anything in JavaScript to do so.

Comment: Did you try to package it?

Comment: No, I was looking for something ready.  Never packaged anything for Meteorjs. I tried underscore.js `_.unescape(str)` but it doesn't work as expected ─ see the string sample above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is then to package Mathias Bynens's solution. It's under MIT license, so no problem copying it. Fortunately it's very easy to add new libraries in Meteor, and you will even be able to publish it on Atmosphere if you want. Here's how:

1. In your project, create a package. Prefix it with `yourMeteorName:` to be able to publish it.

   `meteor create --package bynens-utf8js`
2. Remove the tests, you're not going to modify it. Erase the `package.onTest` callback, and the `js` test file.
3. Add [the `utf8.js` file](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/utf8.js/blob/master/utf8.js) from the GitHub repository.
4. It does the exports itself, so all you need to do is add the file:

   ```
   api.onUse(function(){
       //...
       api.addFiles('utf8.js', 'client');
   });
   ```

And now you have the full library on the client.

Comment: Thanks. I'll do that as soon as I can find the time. For now I'm using this work around: `document.createElement('div').innerHTML = str`